# web2py application level variables

Tags: web-applications, web2py, pickle

I'm new to web2py and web application development in general and I have a certain use case in mind that I'm not sure how to solve given the tools and knowledge that I currently have.

What I want to do is load a pickled class instance once and then keep reusing it for every request that comes into my web2py application. Is there a way to do that in a way that doesn't impact per request performance? In other words is there a way to unpickle the data once and only once and keep reusing it for every request?

Unpickling the data in the model is not the right way to do it because the model is executed on every request and so this will reload the file every time. Similarly doing it in a module is also not the right thing because importing the module will execute the code in the module on every request. The only other thing I can think of is caching the data in ram but I would like to know if there is another way to do it.

Answer (score 1):

Maybe do it in a module and import the object from the module.